# Join two 2D numpy array with one row over another

Tags: python, numpy

Two numpy arrays, lets say

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
b = np.array([[5,6], [7,8]])
```

I would like to combine two arrays into one single array such that the results looks like below array

```
np.array([[1,2],
          [5,6],
          [3,4],
          [7,8]])
```

I tried using concatenate, merge function, but cannot able to find pythonic way to solve this.
Is there is any in built function to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could `stack` on the first axis, and `reshape`:

```
np.stack((a,b), axis=1).reshape(-1,2)
```

Or use `np.c_` and `reshape`:

```
np.c_[a,b].reshape((-1,2))
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6],
       [3, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```

Comment: Use the axis parameter to skip the `swap`: `np.stack((a,b),axis=1).reshape(-1,2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can `column_stack` + `reshape`:

```
out = np.column_stack((a,b)).reshape(4,2)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6],
       [3, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```